# Appium Execution is Very slow on Mac safari browser

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

I am using Appium for browser automaton.

Appium Version: 1.8 (Beta)
xcode: 9.3
iOS : 11.3
Browser: Safari

When i am trying to execute my script on above combination its taking very long time. i have also tried with Appium 1.7 as well.

Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Xpath for locating elements?

Comment: While Execution please keep below things in mind: 1)Replace Implicit wait with Explicit Wait. 2)Reuse Browser Instance. 3)Use of Locator-->a)Id-fastest one. b)name- c)css selector- d)Xpath-It is adding delay of few seconds before & after of every command.